# How to return OKObjectResult as string from Angular http post

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

I'm struggling to find how to pass the payGateR string in my OkObjectResult to my component. Can you please point me in the right direction or explain to me what I'm doing wrong?
Currently, I am returning an object to the angular property of payGateResponse after converting it to string to avoid errors.

I hope I have provided enough info. Any help is appreciated!

ASP.NET Web Api

```
    [HttpPost("PaymentDetails")] 
    public IActionResult PostPaymentDetails(PaymentDetails paymentDetails)
    {
        // Rest of Code

            if (status == "OK" || status == "AUTHORIZED")
            {
                return Ok(new
                { payGateR = decryptResponse });
            }
            else
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
    }
```

Angular service

```
export class PaymentDetailsService {
 formData: PaymentDetails;
 readonly rootURL = 'https://localhost:44386/api/';

 constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

 postPaymentDetails() {
   return this.http.post(this.rootURL + 'order/paymentdetails', this.formData);
 }
}
```

Angular Component

```
export class ShoppingCartFormComponent implements OnInit {
  order: IOrder[];
  payGate: IPayGate[];
  payGateResponse: string;

  cardBrands: string[] = [
    'VISA',
    'MasterCard'
  ];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient,
    private service: PaymentDetailsService, private toastr: ToastrService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    this.service.postPaymentDetails().subscribe(
      res => {
        this.resetForm();
        this.toastr.success('Payment Successful', 'Oh yeah!');
        this.payGateResponse = res.toString();
        console.log(res);
      },
      err => {
        this.toastr.error('Payment Not Successful');
        this.resetForm();
        console.log(err);
      }
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding responseType: 'text' solved my problem.

Source: https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-non-json-data

```
postPaymentDetails() {
    return this.http.post(this.rootURL + 'order/paymentdetails', this.formData, {                     
   responseType: 'text' });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Angular` `HttpClient` default response body is `JSON`. If you want your response object to be something else you should add `'observe': 'body'` to the options of your request.

So your request should look like this

```
 postPaymentDetails() {
   return this.http.post(this.rootURL + 'order/paymentdetails', this.formData, {observe: 'body'});
 }
```

Now you can put anything you want in the body of your response and you can access it via `res.body` in `Angular`

Comment: Thanks for the help Dusan. Your answer put me on the path to a solution.